# How would I go about doing this?

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest, json

First I have my data encoded in the json_encode function.

Looks like this for example:

```
{"test":"test value"}
```

What I want to do is make test into a javascript variable where it can hold the data of "test value".

Comment: var foo = {"test":"test value"}... no idea what you are asking

Comment: Sorry for not being specific enough but the json_encode data is on one page and the page that is using the javascript is on a different page. So for example the json_encode data would be on index.php and the page with the javascript variable would be example.html

Comment: seems like stackoverflow is becoming the homework hotline...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

index.php (use `json_encode` here):

```
<?php
  $foo = array('test' => 'test value');
  echo json_encode($foo);
?>
```

example.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $.get('index.php', function(response) {
    alert(response['test']);
    // this will alert "test value"
  }, 'json');

</script>
```

---

**EDIT1**: example.html *(without-jQuery solution*):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function() {
    var request;
    request = getHTTPObject();
    request.onreadystatechange = sendData;
    request.open("GET", "index.php", true);
    request.send(null);
}

function sendData() {
    if(request.readyState == 4){
    var JSONtext = request.responseText;
    var JSONobject = JSON.parse(JSONtext);

    // notice how variables are used
    var output = JSONobject.test;

    alert(output); // displays "test value"
}


function getHTTPObject(){
    var xmlhttp = false;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        try{
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch(e){
            try{
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch(e) {
                xmlhttp = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return xmlhttp;
}
</script>
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken doesn't that use jquery?

Comment: I can't use jQuery since that's a restriction in my project.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.getJSON('ajax/test.json', function(data) {
  var items = [];

  $.each(data, function(key, val) {
    items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');
  });

  $('<ul/>', {
    'class': 'my-new-list',
    html: items.join('')
  }).appendTo('body');
});
```

straight from the jquery docs...

Comment: Thank you David I was going to add that comment in there too.

Answer (score 0):

Objects are associative arrays. They store key/values pairs. So All you have to do is:

```
var test = function(){}
test["hello"] = "world";
```

This will set `hello` as a variable and `world` as its value.
you can test this by doing

```
alert(test.hello);
```

Replace `hello` and `world` with the json key and value

Hope this help more with this example:
I am using Jquery AJAX to go to index.php resource and return a json object.

index.php

```
<?php
$variables = array('hello' => 'world');
echo json_encode($variables);
?>
```

example.html

```
var test = function(){}
$.ajax({
   url: index.php,
   success: function(json) {
    for(var key in json ){
     var testVarName = key;
     var testVarValue = json[key];
     test[testVarName ] = testVarValue;
    }
}
});
```

So now `test` object has variable `hello` and it value is `world`

Comment: Well the thing is that i mentioned in my other docs that I can't use jquery as that is a restriction in my project.