# AJAX callbacks without jquery

Tags: php, html, ajax, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How would I go about doing this? (AJAX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10658735/how-would-i-go-about-doing-this-ajax)

Since the last time I asked this questions I failed horribly at being specific so I'm going to try again and be as as specific as possible.

First I have my data encoded in the json_encode function.

Looks like this for example:

```
{"test":"test value"}
```

What I want to do is make test into a javascript variable where it can hold the data of "test value". The json_encode data is on a page called index.php and the page that I want the variables to be defined in is called example.html. So what I want is in the javascript portion of the html is have a javascript variable called test and have it equal the string "test value".

Also I don't want jquery for this solution as I was restricted to not being able to do so. I can't use invisible forms and submit them.

Comment: Don't ask a new question.  Improve the existing question.

Comment: I did improve it but it was just that my improvements were all over the place. All for the fact that the question is deep under somewhere now.

Answer (score 0):

Objects are associative arrays. They store key/values pairs. So All you have to do is:

```
var test = function(){}
test["hello"] = "world";
```

This will set `hello` as a variable and `world` as its value.
you can test this by doing

```
alert(test.hello);
```

Replace `hello` and `world` with the json key and value

Comment: But how would the example.html page get the json_encode data from index.php?

Comment: You need to send the json to the browser. So something like: echo json_encode(array('hello' => 'world'));
The browser then gets {"hello":"world"}

Comment: I understand the part where you echo but how would the javascript make it so that it grabs the data from the index.php page and make a variable called hello and have the variable equal the string named world?

Answer (score 0):

```
var json = JSON.parse( {"test":"test value"} )

var testValue = json.test
```

Comment: I can see how that would work but the json_encode data gets changed very frequently so I can't use something as static as that.

Comment: replace the json object with a variable or with a json encoded string.

Comment: Could I do that even if the information is on two different pages?